# h:selectOneMenu change event with p:ajax

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to get the value from on change in h:selectOneMenu using p:ajax.
But I am getting null value always, dont know whats wrong below is the code.

```
<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{userHomeController.gymsSelectType}">

<f:selectItem itemLabel="Close to me" itemValue="closest" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Visited by me" itemValue="visited" />
<p:ajax process="selectMenu" listener="#{userHomeController.selectMenuListener}" event="change" update=":home-form:panel"  />

</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

and the bean class is

```
 public void selectMenuListener() {
    System.out.println("-------- >> " + gymsSelectType); // here null coming
    if (gymsSelectType.equals("a")) {
        //
    } else {
       //
    }
}
```

this is a viewscoped class.
and below setter for the variable gymsSelectType is also prints null

```
public void setGymsSelectType(String gymsSelectType) {
     System.out.println("------------ >> "+gymsSelectType);
    this.gymsSelectType = gymsSelectType;
}
```

Comment: will you perform some logic or just a matter to show/hide data or a panel? because last one can be achieved using JavaScript only.

Comment: have to do some logic based on selection

Comment: Code looks fine although you can use just `<p:ajax update=":home-form:panel" listener="#{userHomeController.selectMenuListener}" />`, it will get called on every value select, which is the default ajax event here. If you will get `null` even with that, the problem is somewhere else. Try adding `<h:messages />` to your facelet to see if there is no error in validation, etc.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Have your tries this

```
<p:ajax process="@this" listener="#{userHomeController.selectMenuListener}" event="change" update=":home-form:panel"  />
```

Comment: 3 years later and this question saved my life. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`<p:ajax partialSubmit="true" listener="#{userHomeController.selectMenuListener}" event="change" update=":home-form:panel"  />`